# Jquery tag removal causing line breaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using a script to highlight text within a container matching the entry in a textbox via the keyup event. What happens is that the text which is matched is wrapped in a span tag like so:
(Text in container 'My text search', search term: 'sear')

```
My text <span class='highlight'>sear</span>
ch
```

When I attempt to remove this to continue a longer search string (user enters another character in the text box), I get:

```
My text sear
ch
```

I ran a scan over it and it doesn't identify as a line break. Is there some way I can simulate a 'delete' character to bring that string back together? Otherwise you can see why a search can't continue for the full word as the tag removal splits the word.

**Removal Method**

```
jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
$(this).find('.highlight').each(function () {
        var cont = $(this).contents();
       $(this).replaceWith(function() { return cont; });         
});
}
```

Comment: What do you want to see (addition of tag, removal of tag, scan for line breaks)? I tried to simplify the question, so I could get a conceptual answer...

Comment: See edit... 'Removal Method'

Comment: Is the text marked up in any other way?

Comment: Text is the inner text of a <dt>,<dd>, or <cite> tag

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with and I have verified that it works... Just had to come at it from a different angle...

```
jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
$(this).find('.highlight').each(function () {
    var cont = $(this).contents();
    var tag = $(this).parent().prop('tagName');
    var tid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var testid = '#' + tid;
    var testTxt= '';

    $(this).replaceWith(function() { return cont; }); 


    testTxt = $(testid).text();
    testTxt = testTxt.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    $(testid).text(testTxt);


});

}
```

This would remove the span tag with the class of 'highlight' and remove any ensuing line breaks left after the tag removal in the inner text of the parent.